# Display Android Thread ID in LogCat

Tags: android, multithreading, eclipse, logcat

By default, LogCat on Eclipse displays 5 informational columns:

```
Time       Level  pid   tag message
```

Is it possible to add a 6th column, displaying **thread id**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: Since 2 weeks have gone by and no concrete suggestion as to how to add a a 6th column for thread id in LogCat has been provided, I can only assume that this isn't possible (currently).

Comment: Here is a feature request for it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28398&thanks=28398&ts=1333722428
Feel free to starr :)

Answer (score 4):

Run ADb in the command shell like this:

```
C:\Temp>adb logcat -v threadtime > t.txt
```

This will run in parallel to your Eclipse session. Once you done with Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from shell and you'll have the log in **t.txt**. It is not as nice as having it in the Eclipse logcat window but will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you - http://android.bigresource.com/Track/android-03XY4qFTQ/

Comment: I am already using android.os.Process.myTid() in my Log.x() but I was asking specifically about adding a 6th column to LogCat in Eclipse, if possible. +1 for the attempt.

Answer (score -1):

```
adb logcat -v threadtime|tee logcat.log
```